TypeScript: Settings Deprecated Migration Guarding and Enforcing
I was messing with typescript recently and in my application I wanted to enforce deprecated settings sanitizing with the power of static type checking. Basically try and make some pattern that is extensible that if a field was to be deprecated it would force the programmer to sanitize that via removing it or migrating it into a new name, etc. I feel like I am close, but I might not know the exact in and out of guarding to get this to work how I want it.
Basically if the there is a field present in UnsanitizedGlobalSettings that should not be it is handled correctly and the type check system throws an issue.
export interface GlobalSettings {
    notifications: {
        system: {
            enabled: boolean;
        },
        social: {
            enabled: boolean;
        },
        gameV2: {
            enabled: boolean;
        }
    }
}

export type DEPRECATED_GameNotificationSettings = {
    notifications: {
        /** @deprecated game has been updated to gameV2, please use that */
        game?: {
            enabled: boolean;
        }
    }
}

export type DEPRECATED_CarNotificationSettings = {
    notifications: {
        /** @deprecated car notifications have been removed */
        car?: {
            enabled: boolean;
        }
    } 
}

export type UnsanitizedGlobalSettings = 
    GlobalSettings |
    DEPRECATED_GameNotificationSettings |
    DEPRECATED_CarNotificationSettings;

/**
 * This function sanitizes and migrates the settings object to the latest version
 * 
 * @param {UnsanitizedGlobalSettings} settings - The settings to sanitize and migrate
 * @return {GlobalSettings} - The settings are mutated and now comply with GlobalSettings
 */
function sanitizeAndMigrateSettings(settings: UnsanitizedGlobalSettings): GlobalSettings {
    // Migrate deprecated `game` settings to `gameV2`
    if ('game' in settings.notifications && settings.notifications.game !== undefined) {
        settings.notifications.gameV2 = {
            enabled: settings.notifications.game.enabled
        };
        delete settings.notifications.game; // Remove the deprecated `game`
    }

    // THIS SHOULD THROW A TYPE ERROR SINCE `car` IS NOT IN GlobalSettings
    // AND SHOULD BE REMOVED
    // Remove deprecated `car` settings
    // if ('car' in settings.notifications) {
    //     delete settings.notifications.car;
    // }

    return settings;
}

const DEFAULT_SETTINGS: GlobalSettings = {
    notifications: {
        system: { enabled: false },
        social: { enabled: false },
        gameV2: { enabled: false }
    }
}

// Usage:
const unsanitizedSettings: UnsanitizedGlobalSettings = {
    ...DEFAULT_SETTINGS,
    notifications: { // Hypothetical user settings loaded from a server or something
        game: { enabled: true }, // The deprecated `game` setting is in the server still
        car: { enabled: true }, // The deprecated `car` setting is in the server still
        system: { enabled: true },
        social: { enabled: false }
    }
};

// Sanitize and migrate the settings, mutating the original object
const settings = sanitizeAndMigrateSettings(unsanitizedSettings);

// Now, `unsanitizedSettings` is guaranteed to be of type `GlobalSettings`
console.log(settings); // TypeScript should knows this is a `GlobalSettings` now...
/**
 * Expected output:
 * {
 *    notifications: {
 *       system: { enabled: true },
 *       social: { enabled: false },
 *       gameV2: { enabled: true }
 *   }
 * }
 */

Any typescript masters want to help make a cool type checking pattern?
